# What are Scalar Observables

Tags: javascript, angular, reactjs, typescript

I am new to Rx. and been having my go at Observables and Subjects. I have recently come a cross a type of observable called a `ScalarObservable`. What is a `ScalarObservable` and how does it differ from a regular observable?

I also noticed you can obtain its values property via its `observbale.value` property. Is this practice recommended?

Answer (score 2):

> Is this practice recommended?

Yes. Scalar observable is an observable with a single value.

Using `value` is demonstrated here : https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/e91d113e49acc9b0e12e2524040fa84cf3fa2c78/spec/observables/ScalarObservable-spec.ts#L10

Comment: Very little is known about them. None of the RxJs documents highlight direct use of them. Can we still use them as is?